# Unable to push Animation rule from Scratch org to Developer Edition Org

Tags: metadata-api, error, trailhead, animations

I am trying to complete App Builder Maintenance trailhead for Summer 19.
However, I don't want to make change manually in the target organization since this is not interesting.

Instead, I am performing changes in Scratch Org, then I pull the changes from Scratch Org to understand where the changes are stored and then I am trying to deploy the metadata changes to the target Developer Edition organization.

When I am doing that, I receive the following error:

```
Record Type Context: bad value for restricted picklist field: m
```

When I remove the value for record type context, I see

```
Animation Frequency: bad value for restricted picklist field: a
```

When I remove both the values, I see error

```
Field recordTypeContext is required.
```

All the errors relate to `force-app/main/default/animationRules/Milestones.animationRule-meta.xml` source file which I pulled from Scratch Org where I did changes manually.

The source file has the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnimationRule xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <animationFrequency>a</animationFrequency>
    <developerName>Milestones</developerName>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <masterLabel>Milestones</masterLabel>
    <recordTypeContext>m</recordTypeContext>
    <recordTypeName>__MASTER__</recordTypeName>
    <sobjectType>Opportunity</sobjectType>
    <targetField>StageName</targetField>
    <targetFieldChangeToValues>Closed Won</targetFieldChangeToValues>
</AnimationRule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some bug in pulling source for the Animation Rule.

[Metadata API documentation says that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_animationrule.htm?search_text=%3F%3DSearchType)

1. valid values for required recordTypeContext picklist enum are `All`,
   `Master`, or `Custom`
2. valid values for required animationFrequency picklist enum are 
   `always` `often` `sometimes` `rarely`

Replacing `m` with `Master` and `a` with `always` helps to get rid of deploy command failure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnimationRule xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <animationFrequency>always</animationFrequency>
    <developerName>Milestones</developerName>
    <isActive>true</isActive>
    <masterLabel>Milestones</masterLabel>
    <recordTypeContext>Master</recordTypeContext>
    <recordTypeName>__MASTER__</recordTypeName>
    <sobjectType>Opportunity</sobjectType>
    <targetField>StageName</targetField>
    <targetFieldChangeToValues>Closed Won</targetFieldChangeToValues>
</AnimationRule>
```